# How to correctly implement operator overloads returning ref so their artifacts can be easily deleted?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Suppose I overload C++ operators such as `~` and `=`, like so

```
Foobar& Foobar::operator~() const {
  Foobar *result = new Foobar();
  // compute *result based on *this
  return *result;
}

Foobar& Foobar::operator=(Foobar& arg) {
  // compute *this based on arg
  // return *this for transitivity
  return *this;
}
```

The operators must return `Foobar&`, not `Foobar` or a pointer, for backwards compatibility and performance reasons.

Then, the user of my class will write stuff like this:

```
Foobar obj0, obj1;

obj1 = ~obj0;
```

Now the return from `~`, which was `new` is lost, so there is no way to `delete` that `new`, so isn't there a memory leak?  If there is a leak, how to design this so there isn't?

Comment: I'm assuming the class is too big to be freely copied. Your `Foobar` should keep a smart pointer to а `FoobarImpl`. Return it by value. This is the only way to maintain sanity.

Comment: Note that performance is not a reason to return a reference.  Unless you are dealing with a very old compiler, the return value optimization or the named return value optimization will make it more efficient to return by value.

Comment: There is no sane design that accommodates return by reference. If this cannot be changed, I'm afraid you will have to live with broken piece of software.

Answer (score 3):

> Now the return from ~, which was new is lost, so there is no way to
>   delete that new, so isn't there a memory leak?

Yes there pretty much is a memory leak in your current implementation. Or at least a high chance for one.

> If there is a leak, how to design this so there isn't?

Why not just leave the new away and go for an local object and return it per value?

Here's what I mean:

```
Foobar Foobar::operator~() {
  Foobar result;
  // compute *result based on *this
  return result;
}
```

I don't see any reason for you to dynamically allocate an object in your example.

If you really need a dynamically allocated object (I don't see any reason why you'd need one...) you might want to use smart pointers.

---

Edit:

Since you clarified that performance might be a problem I'd like to point you to (n)rvo as well as move semantics that @VaughnCato/@Potatoswatter already mentioned (I hope you read their answers alread). I'd suggest reading some articles like [Want speed? Pass by Value.](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)  and [Move Constructor](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/move-constructor/). Chances are that returning by value might not be as much of a performance problem as you think with (n)rvo + move semantics. I'd suggest to implement move semantics and profile with optimizations on afterwards to find out if it's really a problem since it's simply the cleanest solution.

Regarding the smart pointers. I was talking specifically about http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr but since you said in your edited answer that you want a reference and not pointers that might not be a perfect solution either. Something you might want to look into tho.

Other possibilities if move/(n)rvo doesn't give the wanted result would be rather unclean and in my opinion error prone ways around like proxy objects/global containers (maybe something in combination with smart pointers) or other stuff. But I ain't good with this kind of stuff yet and you might comment on @VaughnCato/@Potatoswatter's answers. Since I'm still rather a beginner myself, I think that's all I can suggest to you.

Comment: Can you clarify "smart pointers" ?   Yes, I cannot return per value, due to performance considerations.  Copying the whole class on return is considered too slow.  I have to return a reference.

Comment: @user2581912 Edited my answer. If you need further help you should comment on the answers of the others with more rep. I might not be able to help you with "workarounds" or might make overly unclean/complex suggestions since I don't have much c++ experience yet.

Comment: Thank you everybody.  Yes I am convinced by your multiple answers that returning by reference is not a good idea here.  I can return by value, the syntax for the user is the same so there is no problem with backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that it would cause a memory leak. The normal `operator~` doesn't return by reference but rather by value. The operator should also be const to force you to not mutate the operand. With this approach there won't be any memory leak:

```
Foobar Foobar::operator~() const
{
  Foobar result;
  // compute *result based on *this
  return result;
  // OR
  return Foobar(<stuff to compute result>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a `new` not paired with a matching `delete` causes a memory leak.

You never defined "easy." If you want automatic deletion, you can't. In theory you could return a smart-pointer proxy object which defines `operator Foobar &` and calls `delete` from its destructor. Perhaps you could manage backward compatibility with code that requires `Foobar &` to be the return type, but it would be terrible design. The object would probably destroy itself prematurely, providing only a dangling reference.

Besides something automatic, you can take what you have, be sure to keep a reference `r` to the return value, and **always** remember to call `delete &r;`, even if an exception is thrown. But **never** do that except for on the result of a successful call to `operator ~`.

The fundamental problem is that you have two different semantic requirements for the type `Foobar &`. To free that memory you would have to attach a destructor to a reference, which is totally impossible.

There are many real solutions to look into, such as C++11 move semantics, or a proxy container class to return by value instead of `Foobar`, sidestepping performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

"*I cannot return per value, due to performance considerations. Copying the whole class on return is considered too slow. I have to return a reference.*"

But that's what your code obviously does. It creates a new object of type `Foobar` via new and returns a reference to it. So you have in fact a copy of your other object.
If you want to avoid the copy completely you'll have to go for something like expression templates.

You can achieve this via an intermediate object.

```
template<class Foo>
struct InvertedFoo
{
  Foo const & to_invert;
  InvertedFoo (Foo const &foo_to_invert) 
    : to_invert(foo_to_invert) { }
};

class Foobar
{
  InvertedFoo<Foobar> operator~ (void) const
  {
    return InvertedFoo<Foobar>(*this);
  }
  Foobar& operator= (InvertedFoo<Foobar> const &arg)
  {
    // compute result based on arg.to_invert
  }
};
```

Note that this shifts the "invert"-logic to the assignment operator taking the InvertedFoo argument.

Answer (score 1):

In general, returning by value will be faster than allocating a new object and returning a reference to it.  The return value optimization (RVO) or named return value optimization (NRVO) eliminates the copy, and allocating an object with new isn't as cheap as you might think.  If you haven't already, you should profile it both ways with optimization turned on, and make sure there is a benefit to what you are trying to do.

If you really have to return a reference, one possibility is to use a global container:

```
std::list<Foobar *> global_foobars;

Foobar& Foobar::operator~() const {
  Foobar *result = new Foobar();
  global_foobars.push_back(result);
  // compute *result based on *this
  return *result;
}
```

Then you can go back and delete the objects in `global_foobars` at some appropriate time.

With C++11, you can do this a bit more elegantly:

```
std::list<Foobar> global_foobars;

Foobar& Foobar::operator~() const {
  global_foobars.emplace_back();
  return global_foobars.back();
}
```